# Bucket vs Radix sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I read this comment from another post - and thought to open a separate question:
Bucket sort is more efficient for 'Dense' arrays, while Radix Sort can handle sparse (well, not exactly sparse, but spaced-out) arrays well.
Please help understand how this is so?
As far as I understand ,the 'denseness' of the population will impact the number of buckets equally for both the algorithms.
Also,insertion sort (at each bucket) does not get much impacted by the density - or does it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the distinction behind "dense" vs. "spaced-out" boils down to the uniformity of distribution of data being sorted, with uniformly distributed data considered "dense".

Since bucket sort partitions its input by buckets based on the upper part of the number's value, inputs with uniform distribution would form nice short lists in each bucket. Conversely, inputs with big gaps would form lots of empty lists, and a small number of long lists comparable in length to the original input. This is bad news for the middle step of the radix sort, where individual buckets get sorted, because the "scatter" step does not reduce the original problem all that much.

Radix sort, on the other hand, does not care about the distribution of the numbers in the input: the algorithm takes the same time for any inputs of the same size and the same number of digits in its largest member. Steps for each "digit" take exactly `O(N)` steps; once you are done with the most significant digit, you are done. The distribution of the values being sorted does not play into the timing of the algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I guess 'sparse' and 'dense' in that comment referred to the number of elements ending up in the same bucket.

---

[Bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) splits the input range in a number of buckets, puts each element in the correct bucket and then sorts those buckets.

For instance, if we use 10 buckets to sort numbers between 0 and 999, the first bucket is `[0-99]`, the second `[100-199]`, and so on.

If almost all values are smaller than 100, they will all end up in the same bucket. In that case, bucket sort will be as slow as the algorithm to sort the individual buckets (which could be insertion sort).

---

[Radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) does not use another sorting algorithm, like insertion sort, to sort the buckets, but just applies some sort of bucket sort on each digit separately. For radix sort, it is irrelevant how many elements end up in the same bucket.

To add an example of the latter, let's assume we try to sort `[711, 411, 611, 911, 211]`.
Sorting on the least significant digit will put all elements in the same bucket (the order is unaltered). Sorting on the second significant digit will do the same. Only when the most significant digit is sorted, the elements will be put in different buckets. This has no performance impact.